# Pass form input value to URL

Tags: php, forms, hyperlink

Total new guy to HTML here.

I'm looking to create a search box that passes the typed search term into the URL field.

This is my input form:

```
<form name="search" action="/search/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="topic" value="">
</form>
```

I'd like the search term to go after the `/search/` in the URL. How can this be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the GET form method:

```
<form name="search" action="/search/" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="topic" value="" />
</form>
```

EDIT:

To get the form to send the user to a url like /search//, you can use a javascript function like this:

```
function submitForm(){
    var url = '/search/';
    url += document.search.topic.value + '/';
    // repeat the above line for any other fields you may want to add
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

You can then use this function as an `onClick` handler on a submit button or on the form's `onSubmit`.

Comment: Perfect, although the result in the URL bar is url.com/search/?topic=<searchterm>

How could i just have it /search/<searchterm>/  ?

Comment: @user1742284 To do that, you would need to write some custom javascript.  I'm updating my original post with an example now.

Comment: @G-Nugget sorry to be such a newbie, but how exactly would i write that in my PHP file? what do you mean by onClick handler? I don't have a button for the form, just relying on user pressing enter

Answer (score 0):

you can remove the method="post" since the default is GET method